# Canvas image not drawing?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

The code I'm using to load two images (note that one image is 7MB (I know - I will fix it later)).

```
var loaded = 0;
var img1 = new Image();
var img2 = new Image();
img1.onload = function(){ both() };
img2.onload = function(){ both() };
img1.src = 'map.png';
img2.src = 'ovl.png';

function both() {
    loaded++
    console.log(loaded);
    if (loaded == 2) {
        console.log("LOADED");
        resizeCanvas();
        console.log("RESIZED");
    }
}

function resizeCanvas() {
    //resize code
    drawStuff();
}
function drawStuff() {
    console.log("DRAWSTART");
    ctx.save();
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle="#868f9c";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0,0);
    ctx.drawImage(img2, 0,0);
    console.log("DRAWED");
}
```

As expected the console output is;

```
(index):28 1
(index):28 2
(index):30 LOADED
(index):81 DRAWSTART
(index):90 DRAWEND
(index):64 RESIZED
```

But the images are nowhere to be found, most of the times. Sometimes they appear after ~30 seconds but then no other functions work (I have some panning/zooming stuff aswell).

Note that if I comment out one of the `ctx.drawImage(img[1,2], 0,0);` it works perfectly fine. It seems like drawing two images just isn't working...

Comment: Sounds weird, drawImage is synchronous, so you should not get the DRAWEND in the console before it actually did drawn it. Which browser are your using ?

Comment: @Kaiido Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You should test first with small images in order to check everything is ok. Then for managing big images, you can use a preload library like http://www.createjs.com/preloadjs

Comment: Sry, but that's 60% unrelated to the op code, the images are already pre-loaded